# Display JLabel inside a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

I am trying to display a `JLabel` inside a `JTable` by overriding the `getColumnClass` method like this

```
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("ok");
        String[] columnNames = {"","",""};
        Object[][] data =
            {
                {myLabel, myLabel, myLabel},
                {myLabel, myLabel, myLabel},
                {myLabel, myLabel, myLabel},
            };


        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table = new JTable( model )
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                    return JLabel.class;
            }
        };
```

But instead it displays something like this (hashcode ?)

```
javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=ok,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

What is the problem and how do i fix this?

**EDIT**

The code works fine if use the same logic to display an `ImageIcon`

```
        ImageIcon myLabel = new ImageIcon(path);  // ignore the variable name
```

and change to `getColumnClass`

```
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                    return ImageIcon.class;
            }
```

Comment: read the chapter about renderers/editors in the swing tutorial to understand how they work :-) And emphasizing @mKorbel's answer by repetition: **don't** store components in a table

Comment: Thanks guys, will have a look at the tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [don't put `JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) to the `JTable` or its `Model`, there should be stored [only value used for Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender),

.

```
- Boolean — rendered with a check box.
- Number — rendered by a right-aligned label.
- Double, Float — same as Number, but the object-to-text translation is performed 
  by a NumberFormat instance (using the default number format for the current locale).
- Date — rendered by a label, with the object-to-text translation performed 
  by a DateFormat instance (using a short style for the date and time).
- ImageIcon, Icon — rendered by a centered label.
- Object — rendered by a label that displays the object's string value.
```

- `Renderer` by default returns `JLabel`/`JComponent`
- read Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working code examples

Comment: Thanks, but out of curiousity, i tried adding a simple image instead of `JLabel` and changed the `getColumnClass` to return `ImageIcon.getClass`. It works fine. Why would it work in case of ImageIcon but not in case of JLabel ?

Comment: Why would it work in case of ImageIcon but not in case of JLabel ? because JTable and its model is designated to store only value for JTables view, controled by getColumnClass and everything is painted in Renderer (you don't need to create, but depends of),